# Is possible to change dynamically method for an instance?

Tags: kotlin

I wrote down this code:

```
open class Test(){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "This is test!"
    }
}


fun createTestX(): Test {
    return object : Test() {
        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + "XXX"
        }
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = createTestX()
    println(x)
}
```

It works as expected but I am curious whether is it possible to change method of instance using for  example lambda like this:

```
val x = Test()
x.toString = () -> x.toString() + "XXX"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What you can do

```
class C {
    var example:()->String = this::toString
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val c = C()
    println(c.example())
    c.example = {"ABCDEF"}
    println(c.example())
}
```

## Limitations

Although this works for swapping fields, you cannot use it to override methods. This can be worked around by defining the method to invoke the field.

```
class C {
    var example:()->String = {"ABC"}

    override fun toString() = example()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val c = C()
    println(c)
    c.example = {"DEF"}
    println(c)
}
```

Output:

```
ABC
DEF
```